# Expire Date Condition not Working ACF WordPress

Tags: custom-field

I am trying to Add the Condition if Expire date is smaller than the current date expired in the post. But the condition not working please check the code below.

```
    <?php if (!empty($apply_from)) { ?>
                    <li>
                        <?php 
                    $expire = get_field('expire_date');
                    $date = date('Ymd');
                            if($expire < $date) { 
                    ?>
                            <p>Expired</p>
    
                        <?php
                        } else { 
echo $expire_date; 
                        }   
                            ?>
                    
                    </li>
                    <?php 
                                
                            }
                            ?>
```

Comment: What does "is not working" mean? What are the exact values of `$expire` and `$date`?

Comment: The $date is the Current, and $expire date I will set during post publish which will be bigger than the $date. When $expire date is over it will be smaller than $current shown above the message.

for instance
$date = current date 17-1-2022
$expire = I set 18-1-2022 
Means not Expire

$date = current date 17-1-2022
$expire = I set 16-1-2022 
Means Expire

Comment: (I meant check the real values of these variables, it might be that `$expire` comes in the format `Y-m-d` not `Ymd` e.g.)

Comment: Can you check the link values are correct https://placements.iadm.edu.pk/ here $date is current date

Comment: The current date is 17-1-2022 and the expired date in 2 posts is 2021 but does not show expire value in the post. Remember these all posts are old when I edit any post-working very well for instance first post I edit and change the value then it works well.